# Gitlab-ci not replacing variables in a long curl command inside a script

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I need to call a REST API using a curl command inside a gitlab-ci script.

There are some variables that need to be replaced in the curl command, but if I use same variable, looks like it is not replaced by its value.

Below a piece of my gitlab-ci that works fine without any variable:

```
create_changelog:
  stage: create_changelog

  variables:
    REDMINE_API_KEY: "cbf456d6c74ae85bfbcddfd130c75af4f0977448"

 script:
    - |
      curl -X PUT \
      "https://redmine.example.com/projects/flutter-2/wiki/abc1.xml" \
      -H "cache-control: no-cache" \
      -H "content-type: application/xml" \
      -H "x-redmine-api-key: cbf456d6c74ae85bfbcddfd130c75af4f0977448" \
      -d "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><wiki_page><text>Example</text><parent title=\"Release\"/></wiki_page>"
```

But in case a replace, for example, the apk_key by a variable, like below, I dont get the wiki page created on the server.

```
create_changelog:
  stage: create_changelog

  variables:
    REDMINE_API_KEY: "cbf456d6c74ae85bfbcddfd130c75af4f0977448"

 script:
    - |
      curl -X PUT \
      "https://redmine.example.com/projects/flutter-2/wiki/abc1.xml" \
      -H "cache-control: no-cache" \
      -H "content-type: application/xml" \
      -H "x-redmine-api-key: ${REDMINE_API_KEY}" \
      -d "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><wiki_page><text>Example</text><parent title=\"Release\"/></wiki_page>"
```

How can I use variable in the curl command above ?

Comment: You probably need some way to escape the “ around the variable so it can interpret it correctly, maybe try adding \ before “ like \” ? I’m not sure if there is a syntax for it though

Comment: Did you found a solution? same problem here

Answer (score 0):

It's really should be added in official docs, but with I managed to fix the problem. Below you can see the working code:

```
script:
    - >
      curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json'
      --data '{"chat_id": "'"$CHAT_ID"'",
      "text": "some text"}'
      https://api.telegram.org/bot$TOKEN/sendMessage
```